# Using ado-ada to connect in DataBase

Tags: ada

I'm trying to use this lib to connect to a SQLite database, but I'm not even getting compile it together with my simple source code, I get many compilation errors, the compiler fails to compile, so I wonder if can someone help me showing how I configure and compile this project in windows ....

The link of ado-ada project: https://code.google.com/p/ada-ado/

Btw, have a another good way to connect to a MSSQL or SQLite or MySql database ?

```
C:\Users\AlexB\Desktop\testeSqlIte>gnatmake -P default.gpr
gcc -c -g -O2 -I- -gnatA C:\Users\AlexB\Desktop\ada-ado-0.4.0\src\ado-queries-lo
aders.adb
ado-queries-loaders.adb:25:06: "ADO.STATEMENTS (spec)" depends on "ADO.SCHEMAS (
spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.adb:25:06: "ADO.SCHEMAS (spec)" depends on "UTIL (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.adb:25:06: "ADO.OBJECTS (spec)" depends on "UTIL (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.adb:25:06: "ADO.DRIVERS.CONNECTIONS (spec)" depends on "ADO.
STATEMENTS (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.adb:25:06: "ADO.STATEMENTS (spec)" depends on "ADO.OBJECTS (
spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.adb:25:06: "ADO.OBJECTS (spec)" depends on "ADO.SESSIONS (sp
ec)"
ado-queries-loaders.adb:25:06: "ADO.SESSIONS (spec)" depends on "UTIL (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.adb:25:06: file "util.ads" not found
ado-queries-loaders.adb:25:06: "ADO.QUERIES.LOADERS (body)" depends on "ADO.DRIV
ERS.CONNECTIONS (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.adb:25:06: "ADO.DRIVERS.CONNECTIONS (spec)" depends on "UTIL
 (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.adb:27:06: file "util.ads" not found
ado-queries-loaders.adb:28:06: file "util.ads" not found
ado-queries-loaders.adb:29:06: file "util.ads" not found
ado-queries-loaders.adb:30:06: file "util.ads" not found
ado-queries-loaders.adb:31:06: file "util.ads" not found
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.QUERIES (spec)" depends on "ADO (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO (spec)" depends on "UTIL (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: file "util.ads" not found
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.QUERIES (spec)" depends on "UTIL (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.SQL (spec)" depends on "UTIL (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.PARAMETERS (spec)" depends on "ADO.DRIVERS (
spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.DRIVERS (spec)" depends on "UTIL (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.QUERIES.LOADERS (body)" depends on "ADO.QUER
IES.LOADERS (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.QUERIES.LOADERS (spec)" depends on "ADO.QUER
IES (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.QUERIES (spec)" depends on "ADO.SQL (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.SQL (spec)" depends on "ADO.PARAMETERS (spec
)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.PARAMETERS (spec)" depends on "ADO.DRIVERS.D
IALECTS (spec)"
ado-queries-loaders.ads:19:20: "ADO.DRIVERS.DIALECTS (spec)" depends on "UTIL (s
pec)"
gnatmake: "C:\Users\AlexB\Desktop\ada-ado-0.4.0\src\ado-queries-loaders.adb" com
pilation error
```

Answer (score 1):

The project’s home page (which you link to) says that it requires Ada Util Library and Dynamo. You will need to install them (your error listings show that you definitely need Ada Util, I don’t know about Dynamo).

You ask for Windows build help: do you have a Unix-like environment installed (eg Cygwin)? If so, you can attempt to set up using the supplied `configure` and then `make` in [the ’standard’ Unix way](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/current/smith.html), but if not your best bet is to copy the supplied `.gpr.in` files to the corresponding `.gpr` and edit to remove the `%` variables using your intuition: for example, `ado.gpr.in` starts with

```
with "config";
with "@UTIL_DIR@util";

project Ado is
   Version := "@ADO_VERSION@";
   Library_Dir := "@ADO_LIBDIR@";
```

and `@UTIL_DIR@` needs to be replaced with the directory where `util.gpr` is to be found; then,

```
gnatmake -p -P ado
```

You’ll need a similar approach for Ada Util. As far as I can see, it needs to be configured but it doesn’t need to be built or installed (when configuring ada-ado, you need to add `--with-ada-util=/dir/where/ada-util/source/is`; the library build looks OK against Ada Util 1.7.0, but I needed the 1.6.1 version to get the tests to build.

Comment: Oh, yes yes, I have the cygwin on my PC... btw, how I can install the Dynamo and Ada Util library, where I install this ??

Comment: Ok, I got a lot of errors when I try to build the securyt lib... :(

Comment: Is the ‘securyt lib’ part of dynamo? I think you can do without it.